# TypeError: Cannot read property 'use' of undefined

Tags: node.js, express

Express "^4.16.4" installed and getting error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'use' of undefined".

```
module.exports = {
  registerRoutes(app) {
    app.use('/api', UserRoutes);
  }
};
```

Comment: show the full code, minus any sensitive information. Usually when app is not defined  it shows like that.

Comment: `let app =express()` this line should exist in your code before you try using any middleware

Comment: see the updated answer again which you downvoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();


app.use('/api', UserRoutes);


module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Yup this did it!

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
module.exports = {
  registerRoutes(app) {
    app.use('/api', UserRoutes);
  }
};
```

try this . Also define or import `UserRoutes` in the `js` file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create express app first:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use('/api', UserRoutes);
```